# Load new rows from database for buffering while processing previous loaded data

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, buffering

I'm trying to retrieve, process and send data from database to a web service.

Now I send data concurrently using `Parallel.ForEach` like this:

```
while (true)
{
    var ctrl = new DataController();
    var list = ctrl.GetData();

    if (list == null)
    {
        SaveLogFile("No record retrived", @"C:\log\try-sending-log-");
        continue;
    }
    Parallel.ForEach(list, SendToWebService);
}
```

How can i load and buffer new rows during `Parallel.ForEach` works on sending data?

Answer (score 0):

Parallel.ForEach will wait until all task will be executed.
if you want to start is async than wrap the `Parallel.ForEach(list, SendToWebService);` in `Task.Factory.StartNew` but please take additionaly care of life circle of  all tasks that will be triggered by the `StartNew`